# C++ random char

Tags: c++, random, char

I'm trying to generate a random char like this:

```
char* test = "myname" + GenerateRandomChar();
```

I'm trying to do it without using string. So please don't say use string. Thanks

Comment: So which part of the problem are you having trouble with? Generating a random character? Concatenating it?

Comment: Using the facilities provided to you by the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) *will* make your life so much easier as a C++ programmer. Use them!

Answer (score 5):

if you are writing c code (which it seems you are) then do

```
char buff[8]; //sizeof("myname") + 1 + 1
sprintf(buff,"myname%c", GenerateRandomChar());
```

I am assuming that GenerateRandomChar exists and works

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
char[] test = "myname\0"; // note char[] instead of char*
test[6] = GenerateRandomChar();
```

```
char GenerateRandomChar()
{
    return (char) (random(127-33) + 33);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a sizeof to the buffer so it is char length independent:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

char getRandomChar(){
    static char c = 'A' + rand()%24;
    return c;    
    }

int main ()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    char str[] = "test";
    char buffer[sizeof(str)+1];
    char rnd = getRandomChar();
    sprintf(buffer, "%s%c",str,rnd);
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

Note that the `getRandomChar()` function only gives uppercase letters. You will need to it a bit more sofisticated if you want also lowercase.

This solution assumes you know the size of the initial string in compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it stands is incorrect for two reasons:

1. You're performing a deprecated conversion from `const char*` to `char*`. It should not compile.
2. You're performing pointer arithmetic, not concatenation.

The following expression:

```
"myname" + c
```

where `c` is some `char` does not perform concatenation, but rather pointer arithmetic. It's similar to:

```
char *ptr = "myname";
char c = ' '; // ASCII equivalent is 32
int n = (int) c;
char *s = ptr + n; // s now points out of bounds of ptr
```

If you insist on doing C-style code, then you need to use the standard library functions `strcpy` and possibly `strcat`. Example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

char foo() {
  // return a random character here
}

int main() {
  const char* myname = "myname";
  // enough room to contain new character
  // and null terminator
  char* buffer = new char[strlen(myname) + 2];
  // strcpy includes the null terminator
  strcpy(buffer, myname);
  // We overwrite myname's null terminator
  buffer[strlen(myname)] = foo();
  buffer[strlen(myname) + 1] = '\0';
  std::cout << buffer;
  delete[] buffer;
}
```

Comment: strictly speaking - this question is tagged c++ and in c++ this is not allowed. In C gcc gives you a warning that you are doing a Bad Thing

Comment: @pm100 What is not allowed? The conversion from const char* to char*? That's why I said it won't compile in the comments.

Comment: "foo" + c is not allowed in c++.

Comment: @pm100 it sounds like you haven't bothered to read my answer.